# Expect to have been called failing even after being called

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I have a test case code in Jest.

```
let ticketsTransformer = new TicketTransformer();
    ticketsTransformer.transform = jest.fn(() => results);
expect(ticketsTransformer.transform).toHaveBeenCalled();

const synchronizer = new Synchronizer(
        client,
        ticketsTransformer,
        jest.mock(),
        persister,
        jest.mock()
    );
synchronizer.sync("1999-01-01");
    expect(ticketsTransformer.transform).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

In the `sync` method i tried to `console.log(this.ticketTransformer.transform())` and it gives me the same results stored in `results` variable which means that the method is being called as expected. But I am not sure why still my test case is failing and complaining

```
   Expected number of calls: >= 1
   Received number of calls:    0

      72 |  );
      73 |  synchronizer.sync("1999-01-01");
    > 74 |  expect(ticketsTransformer.transform).toHaveBeenCalled();
         |                                       ^
      75 | });
      76 |
```

Comment: is it a async call, may be before the execution it is trying to expect, can you wait the function to be executed and try to expect it

Comment: I see, how can I wait to expect() ?

Comment: you can check with assertions, try this one https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async#async-await let me know if it solved the pblm

Comment: Thanks alot. Its working now.

Comment: Cool, @ Raheel i have noted the issue and added it as answer, so if anyone face the issue it will be helpful, Kindly update if any info is missed. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was since it was not waiting for the function to execute before itself it was trying to do the expect.

So inorder to wait you can use async and await, also to check a promise call you can use assertions

sample snippet from the official [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async#async-await)

```
it('works with async/await', async () => {
  expect.assertions(1);
  const data = await user.getUserName(4);
  expect(data).toEqual('Mark');
});
```